# Ansible: How to select specific field using register

Tags: ansible

I am using a package specific command for which there is no existing module.  The output (stdout) of the command is either 0 or 1.  I'm trying assign the value of stdout to a variable for later use in the playbook.  However, I cannot seem to isolate the stdout, which is clearly being captured.

```
ok: [hostname1] => {
"dmstate": {
    "changed": true,
    "msg": "All items completed",
    "results": [
        {
            "_ansible_item_result": true,
            "_ansible_no_log": false,
            "_ansible_parsed": true,
            "changed": true,
            "cmd": "/usr/bin/ssh -q hostname1 \"/opt/REDACTED/bin/dmctl -s localhost:8426/dmbroker get DomainManager::hostname1-ampm1::state\"",
            "delta": "0:00:01.808716",
            "end": "2017-09-06 13:28:04.853221",
            "invocation": {
                "module_args": {
                    "_raw_params": "/usr/bin/ssh -q hostname1 \"/opt/REDACTED/bin/dmctl -s localhost:8426/dmbroker                            get DomainManager::hostname1-ampm1::state\"",
                    "_uses_shell": true,
                    "chdir": null,
                    "creates": null,
                    "executable": null,
                    "removes": null,
                    "warn": true
                }
            },
            "item": "hostname1-ampm1",
            "rc": 0,
            "start": "2017-09-06 13:28:03.044505",
            "stderr": "",
            "stderr_lines": [],
            "stdout": "0",
            "stdout_lines": [
                "0"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

}

What I tried was using set_fact: to isolate and search the dmstate.results, but I cannot figure out the correct syntax.

```
  tasks:
- name: check status
  shell: '/usr/bin/ssh -q {{ inventory_hostname }} "/opt/REDACTED/bin/dmctl -s localhost:8426/dmbroker get DomainManager::{{ item }}::state" '
  register: dmstate
  with_items:  "{{ myprocess }}"

- name: find stdout value
  set_fact: stdout_value="{{ item.stdout }}"
  when: item.dmstate.results.stdout == "stdout"
  with_items: dmstate.results

- name: show value of stdout
  debug: var=stdout_value
```

The results of this are here:

```
 fatal: [hostname1]: FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "The conditional check 'item.dmstate.results.stdout == \"stdout\"' failed. The error was: error while evaluating conditional (item.dmstate.results.stdout == \"stdout\"): 'AnsibleUnsafeText' object has no attribute 'dmstate'\n\n
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you are using `with_items`, `item` contains the inner value, so `item.dmstate.results.stdout` has no sense, you have to use `item.stdout` (like you do in the `set_fact`).

Even with this fix, your item will be skipped every time because you are testing the `stdout` value against the `"stdout"` string, but you say that `stdout` is only `"0"` or `"1"`.
I think you could simply remove the `when` clause.

Another problem: each item will overwrite the value of `stdout_value`, so at the end you will only get the last value.

Comment: Thank you!  This resolved my need and helped me better understand what to use.